# PHP: How to send message to more that one specific Android clients

Tags: php, android, session

This is my scenario: There are several Android clients logging in an Apache server (running PHP/MySql). How can I send messages to only some of them (using session)?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any log in facility in your application? If it is there then it is easy to send messages to particular clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need some publisher/subscriber functionality, you'd better use cometd and JavaScript. One alternative is to use long polling, and continuously check from client side if a specific topic has any new message. There are other alternatives too, maybe you could be more specific

Edit
I missed it's an android app. Anyway, you could write your own client or check for an existing one

Answer (score 1):

they use a username/password or id field i guess
you could simply use this field to give them some text

```
if($_SESSION["Name"] == "nametomatch")
{
echo "mytexttodisplay";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that there are many users at a time. So maybe I'll find a way to store the session_id in a database.

Comment: Upon logon of your users you do a $_SESSION["Name"]=$loginname or whereever your loginname is. this way you have this variable $_SESSION["Name"] as long as this session exists. you will have to unset it manually if you don't want it to stay after logging out. ofc to find out "nametomatch" you can use a database maybe with a message-id.